# Lost data of bluestacks

Tags: popup, bluestacks

today i was working with bluestacks after restart pc i faced with pop up (cannot start bluestacks please send a report) and i have a very important file in my bluestacks
i tried copy engine folder to reinstalled bluestacks but it shows the pop up again
my bluestacks is version 5.4
the file that is very important for me is sqlite database that i was building it with a sqlite editor apk and location of db was in DCIM<Shareprefrence
is this file reachable now?
[the pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WzEb.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello again i find out the solution
install PowerISO And go to C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks_nxt\Engine\Nougat32
and open Data.vhd file
in media folder there is your data